# Matching as many as possible not working with look ahead

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to match the wiki list # but not if * or : follows #.
E.g.

```
# Something -> Match
#* Something -> Not match
## Something -> Match
##* Something -> Not matched
##: Something -> Not matched
```

I've come up with the following regular expression :

```
Regex.Match("##* Something", @"^#+(?![*:])\s*(?<Definition>.*?)\s*$").Groups["Definition"]
```

But the Definition value is '#* Something'. I've found that (?![*:]) causes that #+ is matched only once and not more as in the above example - there are two #'s but only first is matched.

How can I write the pattern so I match it ?

Many thanks

Comment: (?!) won't consume. Replace it with a negative character class. Try something like ^#+[^*:]\s*(?<Definition>.*?)\s*$ I didn't have a chance to test that but hopefully it points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your lookahead:

```
@"^(?!#+[*:])#+\s*(?<Definition>.*?)\s*$"
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/iY4vE7/4)

Comment: Although, you can probably just use negation here `^#+\s*(?<Definition>[^*:]+)\s*$`

Answer (score 0):

In case the good ones are "#" followed by space: (Then won't need to define "*" or ":")

```
^#+\s(?<Definition>.*?)\s*$
```

or if (1) character may follow the "#" which is not space yet, but can't be ":" or "*".

```
^#+[^:\*]?\s(?<Definition>.*?)\s*$
```